# How can I "catch" a subview during a swipe gesture on an iOS device?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, uikit

I'm building an iOS board game (similar to scrabble or words) that involves moving around little tiles on the screen and I'm finding the user sometimes has a hard time touching and moving the tiles around because they're too small.  Due to the design of the game, I can't increase the size of the tiles, so I've had to implement some little tricks that make touching and moving the tiles easier for the user and they work well.  The only issue that remains is the user sometimes touches just barely outside the tile and when the user tries to move it, the tile stays where it is.

I have two ideas for how I can fix this...

1. If a tile isn't touched when the user touches the screen, I can use the parent view's touch location to find the closest tile to the touch location and somehow forward the touch event to that tile's view.
2. If a tile isn't touched when the user touches the screen, I can somehow "catch" the tile when the user drags their finger over it as they attempt to move it.

I'd prefer to implement solution #2 since solution #1 has too many problems associated with, not to mention solution #2 is a more realistic experience.  That said, how can I "catch" a tile when the user drags their finger over it and send it touch events to move it where the finger is?

Currently, my tiles are implemented as subclasses of the UIView and they handle the touch events (touchesBegain, touchesMoved, and touchesEnded) directly.  So if the user touches just barely outside the view and drags their finger over the view, it doesn't receive any of the touch events since it didn't receive the initial touchesBegan event.

Thanks in advance for all your wisdom!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should have the "board" view handle all the dragging.  When a touch begins and there is a tile at that point, then start dragging it.  Otherwise check whenever the touch is moved and as soon as you find a tile, start dragging it.

You could override `hitTest:withEvent:` in the board view so that it can still detect when a touch hits a tile, but always return itself so that touch events go to the board view (e.g. record the subview that was hit in a separate member variable, so that you know what to start dragging later on when touch events start coming in).

**More Details**

When handling touches, UIView will use hitTest to find the view that should receive touch events.  The default implementation checks each subview so that the "deepest" subview in the hierarchy gets the touches.  In order for the board view to receive touches, you would have to disable userInteraction on all of the tile views.  But that means you can't use hitTest to find the tile that was touched, since it ignores views that have userInteraction disabled.

So what I am saying is leave userInteraction enabled on the touch views.  But override hitTest on the board view so that it first calls the super implementation in order to find a tile (if the result is `self`, the board itself was hit).  No need to implement your own tile searching.  Something like this:

```
- (UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
  UIView *hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
  if ( hitView != self )
    self.draggingTile = hitView;
  return self;
}
```

Now you know what tile to move in `touchesMoved`.  However, I don't think hitTest is called as the touch is moved, so if no tile has been picked up yet, you may have to call it manually (you can get the `point` and `event` from the touch passed to `touchesMoved`.

Comment: thanks, brian, that sounds like the right approach here. quick question, if i override the hitTest method in the board view, what exactly do I want to do inside of it?  Do i want to cycle through all the tiles and check if the hit point hits any of the tiles?  if so, what's the point of overriding the hitTest method to do that, why wouldn't I just check for that in the board's touch event methods (i.e. touchesBegan, touchesMoved, etc.)?

Comment: Updated answer with more details

Comment: thanks, brian, that helps a lot.  I'll give it a shot!  Also, since my board view contains other types of views than just the tiles, I assume I'll have to check the type of object that is returned from the call to [super hitTest] and make sure it's a tile view.  should I just use [hitView isKindOfClass:[TileView class]] for this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the [UIGestureRecognizer API](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)? I think your best option would be to add a UIPanGestureRecognizer recognizer to your board's view which would then fire back the selector to your UIViewController.

Setup in ViewDidLoad:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                      initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];

[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
```

And then implemented the selector:

```
    - (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
          CGPoint currentPoint = [gesture locationInView:[self view]];
    }
```

When you set up the gesture recognizer you can set parameters to limit the callbacks (only recognize pans with 1 finger, etc. And in the callback you can check the gesture properties to see if the pan in continuing or if it's coming to an end. You can also grab the current point and determine if it's in or near a tile.

Comment: thanks, cesarislaw. question, it seems like the point of your solution is to 1)detect a pan gesture and 2)get its current location so I can do whatever I want with it, is that right?  If not, I apologize, I'm still relatively new to iOS.  If so, why not just use the touchesMoved event method to get this information? thanks again!

Comment: I found that the gesture's provided more control over feedback and did a lot of the low level work for me allowing me to focus on application logic instead of touch detection (is this a tap or a pan? etc.) My application was a drawing app which need to verify that the user was panning from one area to another in a specific order. Gestures are new with iOS4 so if you need 3.2 or older compatibility touch detection is your only option.

Comment: Also I vaguely remember running into some issues which touch events sometimes being intercepted by other views and not passed on (UIScrollView I want to say was especially bad about this).